# Storing whole code in a variable -- Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to store javascript code in a javascript variable.
To explain clearly, please consider example:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>

<a onclick="toggle_visibility('1');toggle_visibility('2');">Click here to toggle visibility of element </a>
<div id="1">This is 1</div>
<div id="2">This is 2</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//document.getElementById('2').style.display='none';
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now suppose all this code is in a variable as a string or something. (i want to do this because i am exporting file to another html page where the code should get copied.) 
I used all variables such as 
using \ before ' and so on. referring to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_special_characters.asp

Comment: Hi @shashank please edit your code, by clicking on the edit button and select the section that has the code and click on the {} button

Comment: Your example seems to be missing...  the example part.  I can't tell what you're asking.  But putting code in a string is usually a bad approach; can you use a function in an external js file instead?  (btw, w3schools is a terrible resource; try developer.mozilla.org.)

Answer (score 2):

Store like this: `var myFunc = function(){ do stuff }`

Run like this: `myFunc();`

Answer (score 0):

To interpret JS code you need to use the JS function `eval()`

```
 var code = "alert('Ok')";

 eval(code);
```

Here is why using `eval()` is a bad idea:

[Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
var quoteElement = document.getElementById('2');
var quote = quoteElement.value;

// or even ..
var quote = document.getElementById('2').value;
```

You would now have the text value of your element in a variable.